# LeetCode 988: Difference between backtracking and depth first search (DFS)

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search, backtracking

I'm confused about the backtracking solution and DFS solution in [LeetCode 988](https://leetcode.com/problems/smallest-string-starting-from-leaf/) (Smallest String Starting From Leaf).

If implementing using StringBuilder, it requires this line of code: `sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1)`, while implementing using String, it doesn't need that line.

Could anyone help solve my confusion?

**Backtracking** (using StringBuilder)

```
String ans = "";

public String smallestFromLeaf(TreeNode root) {
    helper(root, new StringBuilder());
    return ans;
 }

private void helper(TreeNode root, StringBuilder sb) {
    if (root == null) return;
    sb.append((char)('a' + root.val));
    if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
    String candidate = sb.reverse().toString();
    if (ans == "" || candidate.compareTo(ans) < 0) {
        ans = candidate;
        sb.reverse();
    }

    helper(root.left, sb);
    helper(root.right, sb);
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
}
```

**DFS** (using String)

```
String ans = "";

public String smallestFromLeaf(TreeNode root) {
    helper(root, "");
    return ans;
}

private void helper(TreeNode root, String s) {
    if (root == null) return;

    s = (char)('a' + root.val) + s;
    if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
        String candidate = s;
        if (ans == "" || candidate.compareTo(ans) < 0) {
            ans = candidate;
        }
        return;
    }

    helper(root.left, s);
    helper(root.right, s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are not mutable in Java so that means that this line,

`s = (char)('a' + root.val) + s;`

will create a new String object that the recursive function receives. Therefore there is no 'undo' step that backtracking solutions typically have. Whereas in the backtracking solution, only a single StringBuilder object is created and passed. When we return from the base case in the backtracking solution (i.e. reaching a leaf node), we have to undo the step of adding the character to the string builder.

I suggest you to add printing statements to the state of `sb` for the backtracking solution as well as the value of `s` in the DFS and see how it changes every step of the recursion.